# Snowflake MERGE with columns that have spaces in their names

Tags: merge, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm using Snowflake and have a table that has columns with spaces in their names.  The code to create the table is:

```
create or replace MYTABLE (
    "string 1" VARCHAR,
    "number 1" NUMBER(38,0)
);
```

I want to now MERGE some data into the table using the following code:

```
merge into mytable using (
    select * from
        (
            values('a', 4),('b', 5)
        )
) as T ("string 1", "number 1") on FALSE
when not matched then
insert
    ("string 1", "number 1")
values
    ('string 1', 'number 1');
```

When I run the above, I get the following error:

```
Numeric value 'number 1' is not recognized
```

I've tried all manners of wrapping the column names in single quotes, double quotes, and $$ all to no avail.  Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Column could be referenced as `T."""string 1"""`:

```
merge into mytable 
using (
    select * from
        (
            values('a', 4),('b', 5)
        ) 
) as T ("string 1", "number 1")  on FALSE
when not matched then
insert
    ("string 1", "number 1")
values
    (T."""string 1""", T."""number 1""");
```

Output:

[image]

---

Rationale:

```
select * 
from  (values('a', 4),('b', 5)
) as T ("string 1", "number 1");

DESCRIBE RESULT LAST_QUERY_ID();
-- name
-- "string 1"
-- "number 1"
```

`"` is part of the column name `"string 1"` therefore when referencing `"""string 1"""`

Comment: Wow, I never would have thought to triple quote the column name...  Thanks!